# Injection of springSecurityService does not work

Tags: grails, grails-spring-security

In the following code snippet from a controler I get a null pointer exception when trying to access springSecurityService.currentUser. I would expect def springSecurityService to automatically inject the service, what am I missing?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Secured('ROLE_USER')
class TaskController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
def springSecurityService
def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
```

Answer (score 5):

Injecting other Spring beans into your controllers or services is done at the class level and not within a method.

For example, your code should look like:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Secured('ROLE_USER')
class TaskController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    def springSecurityService // inject the bean here, at the class level

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
```